# Swift Combine - Observe property in object inside array of N objects and merge with other properties

Tags: swift, combine

I'm building a graphics app for iOS. Here is my code.

```
class Group {

    /// All the shapes contained in the group
    public var shapes: CurrentValueSubject<[Shape], Never>

    /// The frame of the group
    var frame: CurrentValueSubject<CGRect, Never>

    /// The path to be calculated and displayed to users from the contained shapes
    var cgPath: CurrentValueSubject<CGPath, Never>
}

class Shape {
    var path: CurrentValueSubject<Path, Never>  = .init(Path())
}

struct Path {
    public var points = [CGPoint]()
}
```

So, here is what I want to do but don't know how to do it with Combine.

I want `Group` to observe it's own `frame`, `shapes`, and the `path` of it's shapes (I need to merge all this), so every time each of they change, I can calculate the new CGPath to display and assign it to the `cgPath` property (which will be observed by the View that draws everything).

Please, let me know if this is possible or if there is a better approach to all this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using CombineLatest

Just add the `@Published` property wrapper to the properties you are interested in. Combine already has a predefined `CombineLatest3` method to create a `Publisher` that you can subscribe to. Have fun with it.

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import CoreGraphics

class Group {

    init(shapes: [Shape], frame: CGRect, path: Path) {
        self.shapes = shapes
        self.frame = frame
        self.path = path
        self.observer = Publishers.CombineLatest3($shapes, $frame, $path)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in }, receiveValue: { (combined) in
                let (shapes, frame, path) = combined
                // do something
                print(shapes, frame, path)
            })
    }

    @Published var shapes: [Shape]
    @Published var frame: CGRect
    @Published var path: Path

    private var observer: AnyCancellable!
}

class Shape {
    var path: CurrentValueSubject<Path, Never>  = .init(Path())
}

struct Path {
    var points = [CGPoint]()
}
```

Notice how every change triggers the sink closure.

```
let group = Group(shapes: [Shape(), Shape()], frame: CGRect.zero, path: Path())
group.shapes = [Shape(), Shape(), Shape()]
group.frame = CGRect(x: 1, y: 1, width: 1, height: 1)
group.path.points = [CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)]
```

Comment: Does the `group.path.points` assignment line _also_ trigger the observers??

Comment: Yes, I tested it in a playground. Note that Path is a struct. I would not be triggered if it was a class.

Comment: Exactly right. Classes won’t propagate mutations up the dependency chain.

Comment: After all, I ended up changing my architecture, I went for something more simple, but you guys gave me some great ideas and the correct answers for my question. Thanks a lot!